# Do HttpHeaders get encrypted when not using https

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is plenty of discussion for this regarding https. But do the headers get encrypted when not using https (so plain http)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nop :)

-- Everything sent over Http is pure plain-text. However, stuff like your view state and session id, might get encrypted by the IIS server side.

Comment: Thanks :) So just confirming that if I use custom HttpHeaders for transmitting username and password, they are sent as plain text?

Comment: Yep.. Http doesn't do any encrypting for you. If you're interested you can use Wireshark (freeware'ish) to see everything that is sent over the network.